# Editing e-commerce website values

Tags: c#

Each product in my e-commerce website has Arabic and English values for the title, description and excerpt. I have this method `EditProduct` to update those values based on current culture (Arabic or English)

```
public void EditProduct(string element, string text1, string text2, bool edit1, bool edit2, string culture)
{
    var product = DoSomeMagicToGetAProduct();

    if (element == "title")
    {
        if (culture == "en")
        {
            if (edit1)
            {
                product.Title = text1;
            }
            if (edit2)
            {
                product.TitleAr = text2;
            }
        }

        if (culture == "ar")
        {
            if (edit1)
            {
                product.TitleAr = text1;
            }
            if (edit2)
            {
                product.Title = text2;
            }
        }
    }

    if (element == "description")
    {
        // similar codes here
    }

    if (element == "excerpt")
    {
        // similar codes here
    }

    product.Save();

}
```

The method works well, but I think I can improve the way I write it to be more elegant.
Any suggestions?

Comment: What are Title and TitleAr for? What do edit1 and edit2 mean?

Comment: @Winston TitleAr is the arabic value of Title (english value). edit1 == true means user is editing text1.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think the code is a little dodgy, and the design is dodgy. I'd store the translation in a dictionary of some sort.

But addressing your immediate question, to simplify the code you have, you could do....

```
public void EditProduct(string element, string text1, string text2, bool edit1, bool edit2, string culture)
        {
            var product = DoSomeMagicToGetAProduct();

            var arText = culture == "ar" ? text1 : text2;
            var enText = culture == "en" ? text1 : text2;
            var updateEn = culture == "en" ? edit1 : edit2;
            var updateAr = culture == "ar" ? edit1 : edit2;

            if (element == "title")
            {
                if (updateEn) product.Title = enText;
                if (updateAr) product.TitleAr = arText;                    
            }

            if (element == "description")
            {
                if (updateEn) product.Description = enText;
                if (updateAr) product.DescriptionAr = arText;   
            }

            if (element == "excerpt")
            {
                if (updateEn) product.Excerpt = enText;
                if (updateAr) product.ExcerptAr = arText;   
            }

            product.Save();

        }
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Nicholas. this looks better than mine. 
I also appreciate your suggestion on my design, but I'm afraid storing those values in some kind of dictionary is too much, since the website only support arabic & english.

Comment: This certainly does tidy up the code, however removing parentheses could possibly contravene any coding standards in place.  @Anwar Chandra I would suggest reading page 23 & 24 of C# Code Style Guide http://www.sourceformat.com/pdf/cs-coding-standard-bellware.pdf for inspiration.

Comment: instead of the ifs, use switch case statements.

Answer (score 0):

You should try using a switch statement for the languages.  Also move the languages to be the first statements to check instead of the element.  This combined should reduce the size of your code.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06tc147t%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Then for the edit booleans you can do this instead.

```
            if (edit1)
            {
                product.Title = text1;
            }
            else 
            {
                product.TitleAr = text2;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why should you need if-else for culture change? .Net resources is the way to show localized web pages as per culture on user machine.
You should have just one product.title field and 2 resource files, one neutral culture which contains english words and another 'ar' culture which holds the arabic translation.

Refer to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227427.aspx for an overview of asp.net resources.

Hope this helps. If I am missing something here please post.

Comment: Yes, localization in the website already handled by .Net resources. product isn't resource, and my users need to input its values manually on a daily basis.